# Obtain the first id from a sorted Array through Comparator

Tags: android

I use the following method to sort an array from an sqlite database:

```
public void sortNearby(final double lat, final double lng) {
        Arrays.sort(videoLocationsDB, new Comparator<VideoLocationDB>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(VideoLocationDB lhs, VideoLocationDB rhs) {

                double lat1 = lhs.latitude;
                double lng1 = lhs.longitude;

                double lat2 = rhs.latitude;
                double lng2 = rhs.longitude;

                double lhsDistance = countDistance(lat, lng, lat1, lng1);
                double rhsDistance = countDistance(lat, lng, lat2, lng2);
                if (lhsDistance < rhsDistance)
                    return -1;
                else if (lhsDistance > rhsDistance)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
        });
        videoLocationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

How can I obtain the Id of the first object from the sorted array? for example I need to get `VideoLocationDB.id` of the first object

Comment: `videoLocationAdapter.getItem(0)` ?

Comment: that would get the item.. he wants the ID. so it would be: videoLocationAdapter.getItemId(0)